# Why java lambda jumps filter

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following code:

```
public List<MainObject> filterListByNestedObjectAttribute(List<MainObject> mainObjects) {
    List<MainObject> mainObjectFiltered = mainObjects.stream()
                .filter(mainObject -> {
                    NestedObject nestedObject = Collections.max(mainObject.getNestedObjects(), Comparator.comparing(nestedObject -> nestedObject.getDate()));
                    return businessValidation(nestedObject) || businessValidation2(nestedObject);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The point is, the filter is NEVER called...
Doesn't matter what I do, the filter is ignored and the result of the stream is the **same** list!!

Am I doing something wrong?
The call to another Java lambda breaks the filter call?

---

EDIT

I applied the same code in the void main and worked...

In unit test the IDE is caching the value of filter, I don't know why...

Code:

```
public class LambdaJumpsFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaJumpsFilter lambdaJumpsFilter = new LambdaJumpsFilter();

        NestedObject nestedA1 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new NestedObject("A", OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(3));
        NestedObject nestedB1 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new NestedObject("B", OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2));
        NestedObject nestedC1 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new NestedObject("C", OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
        NestedObject nestedA2 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new NestedObject("A", OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
        NestedObject nestedB2 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new NestedObject("B", OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2));
        NestedObject nestedC2 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new NestedObject("C", OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(3));

        MainObject mainObject1 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new MainObject();
        MainObject mainObject2 = lambdaJumpsFilter.new MainObject();

        List<NestedObject> nestedObjects1 = new ArrayList<>();
        nestedObjects1.add(nestedA1);
        nestedObjects1.add(nestedB1);
        nestedObjects1.add(nestedC1);

        List<NestedObject> nestedObjects2 = new ArrayList<>();
        nestedObjects2.add(nestedA2);
        nestedObjects2.add(nestedB2);
        nestedObjects2.add(nestedC2);

        mainObject1.setNestedObjects(nestedObjects1);
        mainObject2.setNestedObjects(nestedObjects2);

        List<MainObject> mainObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        mainObjects.add(mainObject1);
        mainObjects.add(mainObject2);

            List<MainObject> mainObjectFiltered = mainObjects.stream()
                    .filter(mainObject -> {
                        NestedObject nestedObjectMax = Collections.max(mainObject.getNestedObjects(), Comparator.comparing(nestedObject -> nestedObject.getDateTime()));
                        return lambdaJumpsFilter.businessValidation(nestedObjectMax) || lambdaJumpsFilter.businessValidation2(nestedObjectMax);
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(mainObjectFiltered.size());
    }

    private boolean businessValidation2(NestedObject nestedObject) {
        return nestedObject.equals("D");
    }

    public boolean businessValidation(NestedObject nestedObject){
        return nestedObject.value.equals("A");
    }

    public class MainObject{
        private List<NestedObject> nestedObjects;


        public List<NestedObject> getNestedObjects() {
            return nestedObjects;
        }

        public void setNestedObjects(List<NestedObject> nestedObjects) {
            this.nestedObjects = nestedObjects;
        }
    }

    public class NestedObject {
        private String value;
        private OffsetDateTime dateTime;

        public NestedObject(String value, OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
            this.value = value;
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateTime() {
            return dateTime;
        }

        public void setDateTime(OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }
    }

}
```

---

I know it was despair, but I spent hours looking for something like that.

I found the why not DEBYG not pass in the filter ...

As I'm doing unit testing, I spend the same value and (I don't know why) the IDE already knows the value of the filter and ends up ignoring the filter.

Comment: Post code that compiles. This code doesn't, so it can't possibly do anything.

Comment: Post a [mcve], so that we can reproduce your issue!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose If you use `[mcve]` it will render [mcve]

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks!

Comment: if you're receiving the same list then that means the predicate to`filter` is _always_ evaluating to `true` otherwise it would return a list with fewer elements that the source list. make sure the logic in the `filter` operation is correct and the methods being called are doing the expected thing.

Comment: Maybe the condition is always true? Try putting a `System.out.println` call in the filter and print the return value before you return it. See if every print is true.

Comment: I added... the conditions is not always true, but as I am doing unit test the list is always the same...

Comment: `nestedObject.equals("D");` should probably be `nestedObject.value.equals("D");` Maybe this is also a mistake in your real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I dont belive that filter is skipped. To me, your filter logic is wrong and returns `true` for all elements (assuming this is not what you expect) or you only think that some of elements should be skipped while it is not true.

try this

```
List<MainObject> mainObjectFiltered = mainObjects.stream()
            .filter(mainObject -> {
                NestedObject nestedObject = Collections.max(mainObject.getNestedObjects(), Comparator.comparing(nestedObject -> nestedObject.getDate()));
                boolean result=businessValidation(nestedObject) || businessValidation2(nestedObject);
                System.out.println("Im am indeed filtering: "+result);
                return result;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and tell me that there is no output on the console :)

The only case that filter could be skipped is if stream would be empty, but that is not the case as far as I can tell from your description